# elliptic abacus

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I use abacus  to calculate confidence interval in binomial when nf<5 or/and n(1-f)<5 too.
My question is : is it possible to draw this with tikz or with another package?
any advice? thank you

[image]

Comment: Do you know the functions for the plots? Or you have the data?

Comment: sorry I don't know we study this in statistic .

Comment: I am not specialist , but perhaps this link  :http://www.researchgate.net/publication/233117923_Generalised_ClopperPearson_confidence_intervals_for_the_binomial_proportion is it?

Comment: You want us to do all the work and you don't even have the functions; don't expect much help without _any_ effort yourself. (Just saying...)

Comment: @Haouam Here is a paper with your needed formulas for various methods. http://lejpt.academicdirect.org/A03/075_110.htm and several plots like what you want.  Notice that individual points are calculated and then the curve between is fitted (probably, by hand; but possibly with Bezier curve.   And the term 'elliptic abacus' is used by what author as I have not seen that term before.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know those plots but here's the axes definition, it should help you to start.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{sansmath} %for the sans serif font

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=10cm, height=10cm, % dimensions
    xmin=0, xmax=10,
    ymin=0, ymax=10,
    grid=both,
    grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
    major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
    xtick={0,...,10},
    ytick={0,...,10},
    xticklabels={0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100},
    yticklabels={,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100},
    ticklabel style={font=\footnotesize},
    minor tick num=9, % ticks between each major tick (between 0 and 10 = 9)
    xlabel=$f$,
    ylabel=$P$,
    x label style={font=\sansmath,at={(axis description cs:1,0)},anchor=south west},
    y label style={font=\sansmath,at={(axis description cs:0,1.01)},rotate=-90,anchor=south},
]

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```